# MySQL skip-name-resolve

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I use MariaDB / MySQL in 1 dedicated server.
All databases & PHP are in local server.
I don't use remote server.

When running mysqltuner, i received recommendation to use "**skip-name-resolve**".

So i added this code in my.cnf

```
skip-name-resolve
```

and i restarted mysql.

My questions are :

1. Will using `skip-name-resolve` speed up my mysql ?
2. When i check my mysql.db & mysql.user tables, i still see my server hostname (such as "**host.myserver.com**" / my public dedicated IP (not 127.0.0.1) in the "host" column. Should i change the value of "host" column too? Or i just need to leave everything as-is after adding skip-name-resolve?

Comment: While you are questioning that tool, note that `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is usually a waste of time.

Comment: @Rick James, do you mean i do not need to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` regularly ?

Comment: It is mostly a waste of time.  With InnoDB, the engine mostly keeps the BTrees "optimized".  Even in BTrees with a lot of apparent "free" space, `OPTIMIZE` may not produce a noticeable improvement.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. If you are not connecting to your server from a remote host, then no, this is not going to speed up your mysql server. Slow DNS connection plus lots of remote hosts is the scenario when this option helps.
2. If you turn off the name resolution, then entries with IP addresss only will be used by mysql when checking the access rights.

See mysql documentation on [DNS Lookup Optimization and the Host Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/host-cache.html) for further details.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.