# Slow Update, Delete and Insert Queries under MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization, myisam

our server was updated from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 20 with MariaDB. Unfortunately, the loading time of the website has become slower. Normally MariaDB should be faster than Mysql. I've found that, quite simply, update commands on the website take about 7 seconds sometimes. However, if I enter these update commands directly into the database via myphpadmin, they only take 0.0005ms.

It seems to me that MariaDB has a problem with update commands when they occur frequently. This was never a problem with mysql. Here's an query example:

```
UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY users
SET user_video_count = user_video_count + 1
WHERE user_id = 12345
```

The database format is MyISAM.

I have no idea what could be the reason. Do you?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could be missing [skip-name-resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011221/mysql-skip-name-resolve#39011403) in the configuration. Is `user_id` the primary key of the table? By frequently do you mean multiple concurrently? If so Innodb would be a good choice. Aria would be a better choice than MyISAM too as a minimum.

Comment: Thank you very very much for helping me. I appreciate it alot. Yes user_id is the primary key. I mean with frequently, when its live and get traffic. You mean I should add skip-name-resolve to my.cnf. Please clarify this. If this does not work, I should switch to innodb?

Comment: Update: I see skip-name-resolve is already in the my.cnf. Do you really think, that myisam and MariaDB could be the problem?

Comment: Was it just updated from `Ubuntu 16` to `Ubuntu 20` ? Or did you go from 16 to 20 AND did an update of MySQL -> MariaDB ?   Did you TEST this migration, or did you just assume that it would work ?  Most likely reason: User did not take enough time to test.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Luuk. I tested the migration. I said to my host, that I need a testserver with a backup of the original one and I paid for. We made the migration frist on the backup server. From 16 to 18 and then to Ubuntu 20. Plesk and Ubuntu20 means > MariaDB.  This problem I doestn have on the testserver, because I was alone on the server. This morning we did the update on the main server without any problems.

Comment: But after the migration the server gets under load and the problem came up. I figured out, It has to to with update Queries. The weired thing is, that If I do the same query in myphpadmin its really fast. So I guess it has to do with many updates at the same time. But I use Low priority and it was no problem with mysql. I hope so much anyone knows the reason. At the moment I install a testdb and try InnoDB instead of myisam but could this really be the reason? I dont think so.

Comment: If MyISAM performs poorly under load, switch to InnoDB and don't look back. InnoDB handles concurrency **far better** than do MyISAM and Aria.

Comment: Thank you very much for help O. Jones. Ok, I will switch to InnoDB but do you know the reason, why MyISAM and mysql works for 20 years very fast and brilliant and now with MariaDB I have this problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be something as simple as a `SELECT` searching for something in `users`.  *Note*, InnoDB would not suffer this problem.

`MyISAM` necessarily does a *table lock* when doing `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or `DELETE`.  (Also `ALTER` and other DDL statements.)  If there are a lot of connections doing any mixture of writes and even `SELECTs`, the locks can cascade for a surprisingly long time.

The real solution, whether in MariaDB or [especially] in MySQL, is to switch to InnoDB.

If this is a case of high volume counting of "likes" or "views", then a partial solution (in either Engine) is to put such counters in a separate, parallel, table.  This avoids those simple and fast updates fighting with other actions on the main table.  In an extremely high traffic area, gathering such increments and applying them in batches is warranted.  I don't think your volume needs that radical solution.

MySQL has all-but-eliminated MyISAM.  MariaDB may follow suit in a few years.

To address this:

> the same query in myphpadmin its really fast

The problem is not with how you run it, but what else happens to be going on at the same time.

(`LOW PRIORITY` is a MyISAM-specific kludge that sometimes works.)

MyISAM does "table locking"; InnoDB does "row locking".  Hence, Innodb can do a lot of "simultaneous" actions on a table, whereas MyISAM becomes serialized as soon as a write occurs.

**More**  (Now focusing on InnoDB.)

Some other things that may be involved.

If two `UPDATEs` are trying to modify the *same row* at the same time, one will have to wait (due to the row locking).

If there is a really large number of things going on, delays can cascade.  If 20 connections are actively running at one instance, they are each slowing down each other.  Each connection is given a fair share, but that means that they all are slowed down.

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see what is running -- not "Sleep".  The process with the highest "Time" (except for system threads) is likely to be the instigator of the fracas.

The slowlog can help in diving deeper.  I turn it on, with a low enough `long_query_time` and wait for the 'event' to happen.  Then I use `pt-query-digest` (or `mydumpslow -s t`) to find out the slowest queries.  With some more effort, one might notice that there were a lot of queries that were "slow" at one instant -- possibly even "point queries" (like `UPDATE ... WHERE id=constant`) unexpectedly running slower than `long_query_time`.  This indicates too many queries and/or some query that is locking rows unexpectedly.  (Note:  the "timestamp" of the queries is when the query *ended*; subtract `Query_time` to get the start.)  [*SlowLog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)

**More**

`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2`, as you found out, is a good fix when rapidly doing lots of single-query transactions.  If the frequency becomes too large for that fix, then my comments above may become necessary.

There won't be much performance difference between =2 and =0.

As for `innodb_flush_log_at_timeout`.  Please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Binlog%commits'

As for `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`...  I don't think that changing that will help you.  If one of your queries aborts due to that timeout, you should record that it happened and retry the transaction.

It sounds like you are running with `autocommit = ON` and not using explicit transactions?  That's fine (for non-money activity).  There are cases where using a transaction can help performance -- such as artificially batching several queries together to avoid some I/O.  The drawback is an increased chance of conflicts with other connections.  Still, if you are always checking for errors and rerunning the 'transaction', all should be well.

**innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit**

When that setting is "1", which is probably what you originally had, each Update did an extra write to disk to assure the data integrity.  If the disk is HDD (not SDD), that adds about 10ms to each Update, hence leading to a max of somewhere around 100 updates/second.  There are several ways around it.

- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0 or 2`, sacrificing some data integrity.
- Artificially combining several Updates into a single transaction, thereby spreading out the 10ms over multiple queries.
- Explicitly combining several Updates based on what they are doing and/or which rows they touch.  (In really busy systems, this could involve other servers and/or other tables.)
- Moving the counter to another table (see above) -- this allows interference from more time-consuming operations on the main table.  (I did not hear a clear example of this, but the slowlog might have pointed out such.)
- Switch to SSD drives -- perhaps 10x increase in capacity of Updates.

I suspect the social media giants do all of the above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answeser. I appreciate it every single second you invest here. I read it carefully multiple times. I switched now to InnoDB. Its better but the slowest queries are still the update querys. While all other queries run within 0.00011s the update queries needs under load 0.09711s (not via myphpadmin, there its fast). I know this is not slow but there has to be a reason. All "wheres" in the query has an index and only 1 row is affected. Is there any optimization? Thank you for putting me in the right direction.

Comment: PS: I find out, that its not only Update, also Insert and Delete is compared to Select very very slow under load. For example: UPDATE sessions SET session_time = 1645636144 WHERE session_id = '4564565645655'; there is an index on session_id and under myisam with mysql this runs in 0,00010s. Under load with mariadb I have 0.33868s. I would like to hire you, is this possible?

Comment: @labu77 - OK, my simple answer was not sufficient.  I added More.

Comment: @labu77 - And yes to your last question:  Contact me: mysql at rjweb dot org

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have fixed the problem last evening and I have answered my question in this topic. Would you please review it and answer my last question in it? iI I ever have a problem with sql again, I will not hesitate to contact / hire you instead of searching may days for solution. Thank you for the kind offer.

Comment: With the new setting of innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0 the slow query log is empty. Yes, autocommit is ON. You said: "always checking for errors and rerunning the 'transaction', all should be well". How do I check that? To innodb_flush_log_at_timeout: Binlog_commits = 0, Binlog_group_commits = 0. What does that mean now? Do I need innodb_flush_log_at_timeout? To move the Counter to a other table is a good idea, what I keep in mind. The server has already a SSD of 400GB. I dont understand, why with SSD I had such problems without innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0 or 2. Thank you

Comment: I assume (without any specific evidence) that sometimes there are over 1000 updates in a single second.  When that happens, the I/O, even on SSD, cannot keep up.  The setting of 0 or 2 lets it process more than 1000/second without I/O being a bottleneck.

Comment: It is impossible that there are so many updates at the same time. At most 10-50 per second but never more. What other reasons can there be? Can you comment on the timeout and binlog commits you asked about? Thank you very much.

Comment: @labu77 - An `ALTER TABLE` that takes minutes will block thousands of `UPDATEs`.  With MyISAM (but not with InnoDB), a long `SELECT` can block lots of Updates.  So, no, I don't have the "complete" answer to your situation.

Comment: @labu77 - I forget what Binlog%commit was about -- The conclusion is that there is "not a problem".

Comment: thank you very much. I have send you a banana latte via paypal. I saw your website last night and was reading many hours. It's amazing how much sql knowledge you have. It is my pleasure to write with you here. Can I ask you one more question? My database has 114 tables. Smaller tables with mostly select queries are in Aria now and all others in innodb. Aria 77 / Innodb 44. Is this mix of engines a problem and should I switch with the Aria tables also to Innodb from a performance perspective?

Comment: @labu77 - Thanks.  I can think of 2 issues when mixing engines.  A transaction must be limited to tables of a single Engine.  Also, one must be careful when laying out RAM; each engine needs as much RAM as you are willing to give it for its caching (`innodb_buffer_pool_size` for InnoDB).  So, each engine must play fair and not be too greedy.  I do not [yet] have any tuning recommendations for Aria.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using MariaDB, you can use tools like EverSQL to find missing indexes or discover redundant indexes (e.g. you have an index on user_video_count that you don't really need)

Comment: Thank you very much Oded. This is usefull, I will try this. Do you know the reason, why MyISAM and mysql works for 20 years very fast and brilliant and now with MariaDB I have this problems with simple udpate query?

Comment: This is very common. MariaDB Optimizer and MySQL Optimizer are not so similar as people think.  Each DB optimizer has pros and cons

Comment: you mean its very common, that MariaDB cant handle updates on myisam tables under load?

Comment: I believe it's very hard to tell what causes an issue after upgrading / changing OS or DB type.
I would start with comparing the configuration of both databases (for example, how large is is the buffer pool size in each of them), then compare explains of the queries on both databases, especially in concurrent load. You need to pinpoint the root cause of the problem first, and then figure out how to fix it specifically for MariaDB.
In general though, as @rick.james wrote, I would strongly consider upgrading to InnoDB, as MyISAM is not very reliable and a very old technology.

Comment: Thank you very much. I switched now to InnoDB. Its better but the slowest queries are still the update querys. While all other queries run within 0.00011s the update queries needs 0.07711s. I know this is not slow but there has to be a reason. All "wheres" in the query has an index. Do you know the reason why udpates are so slow in mariadb and now innodb compared to mysql and myisam? Is there any optimization?

Comment: If you could post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE FROM users 
WHERE user_id = 12345;   we could all know the situation on available indexes to consider.  Please also post results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE users;  B) SHOW INDEX FROM users;  C) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'users';  for more in depth analysis.

Comment: Hello Wilson Hauck, thank you very much for helping me. I really go crazy with this problem. I find out, that its not only Update, also Insert and Delete is compared to Select very very slow under load. For example: UPDATE sessions SET session_time = 1645636144 WHERE session_id = '4564565645655'; there is an index on session_id and under myisam with mysql this runs in 0,00010s. Under load with mariadb I have 0.33868s. I dont know exaclty what you need. coule you please explain again? If paid support is possible, I will do.

Comment: @labu77 - clarification...  Was the 0.33868s using InnoDB?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, it was InnoDB. In Mysql and Myisam I had never such times. I will to your questions under your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to thank everyone who helped me. I really appreciate that people try to invest their precious time.

I would like to tell you how I managed to fix the problem with the slow update, insert and delete queries.

I added this value to the my.cnf file:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

After I restarted the mysql server, the server load dropped suddenly and the update, insert and delete queries also dropped from about 0.22222 - 0.91922 seconds to 0.000013 under load. Just like it was before with Myisam and Mysql and how it should be for so simple updates with a index.

I have to mention that I have set all tables that receive frequent insert or update commands to INNODB and those with many selects to ARIA.

Since we don't handle money transactions, it's no a problem for me if we lose last seconds due to

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

I go even further. I can also live with it if we lose the last 30 seconds in a failure.

So I have also set:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout = 30
```

I'm currently testing

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

But so far, I do not see a significant improvement with

```
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout = 30
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

instead of

```
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout = 1 (default)
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

So the main goal was:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2

or

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

Does anyone know, why:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout = 30
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

is not faster then just

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

?

I also dont understand, why this settings are not more popular because many websites could have big improvements in case of speed, if they dont mind of loosing a second or more.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I added to my Answer.